# How to scramble a string?

Tags: java, cryptography

When comparing passwords, there is always an issue of keeping them in memory. Instead, the moment a password is introduced, i'd like to replace it with its md5 snapshot (or any other hash producing function)

Assuming you have a Key Value pair `String password = "Secret";`, what is the simplest way to scramble "secret" to something unique?

Comment: Might get some better answers over at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could try wrapping it in WeakReference.

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee How would that help?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It would release it from memory asap. Of course, your way is better.

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee The trouble is, your `WeakRef` may get cleared while you still need it---and on the other hand even when the ref is cleared, the object itself won't be erased from memory. There's even no guarantee as to when it will be GC'd. That's why I ask how it could help in the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a MessageDigest. Something like this:

```
MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
algorithm.reset();
algorithm.update(password.getBytes());
byte bytes[] = algorithm.digest();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (byte b : bytes) {
    String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & b);
    if(hex.length() == 1)
        sb.append('0');
    sb.append(hex);
}
result = sb.toString();
```

Also, watch out of the NoSuchAlgorithmException that can be thrown by the getInstance method if the MD5 algorithm is somehow not available.

Answer (score 5):

As soon as you have the password in a `String`, you have already failed because you won't be able to zero it out. It will linger on the heap until another object overwrites it by chance. The first thing you must ensure is that you only keep the password in a `char[]` and manually zero it out as soon as possible. As for hashes, JDK comes with support for them. Check out [`java.security.MessageDigest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Messagedigest class to produce the hash

But I think what's important is not to get the whole password in memory - if you are reading it via some kind of byte stream read it directly into the message digest byte by byte - using the update method of the message digest class, then after you finish reading call digest to get the result.